# Can loadUI be used to load test a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, load-testing, loadui

I am looking at the basic intro for [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) and it seems to be for [webpage load testing](http://www.loadui.org/Getting-Started-with-loadUI/your-first-load-test.html)

Is there a way to load test wcf services with it?  or is that just not its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it with SoapUI test cases which define a test that LoadUI will call as part of the Load Test. Drag a SoapUI Runner component from the toolbar and choose a test case that you have defined in SoapUI and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

From the site:

## What is loadUI?

loadUI is a Performance Testing Tool. loadUI can be used for testing Web Services such as SOAP and RESTful as well as HTTP Services, JMS and Databases.. LoadUI is an Open Source and completely free tool. LoadUI is being produced by the community and led by the Open Source company eviware.